# Write Flowfile content into Excel (or xls) file by Groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, apache-poi, apache-nifi

I am using Apache Nifi to extract data SQL query into XLS file.

I use ExecuteQuery to extract data into Avro, then to CSV using CSV RecordWriter

Now I should to have my data in an XLS file, to do, I am using this Groovy script but it's not working:

```
// import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*
// import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.io.*

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.*

def flowFile = session.get()

if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    try {

     inputStream.writeTo(outputStream)
 
// i tried also outputStream.write(inputStream)
 
//i  tried also to retrieve the excel file with:
 //Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
//and write with : outputStream.write(wb)
 
    }
    catch(e) {
     log.error("Error during processing", e)
     session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
    }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

I have this error:
[image]

Edit:
I changed my script and had an other error:

```
@Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.9'))
import com.opencsv.CSVReader
@Grapes(@Grab(group='com.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='4.2'))
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.*
import java.nio.charset.*
import java.io.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def flowFile = session.get()
def date = new Date()

if(!flowFile) return


flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
        SXSSFSheet sheet1 = null;
        CSVReader reader = null;
        Workbook wb = null;
        String generatedXlsFilePath = "/home/";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
  
  def filename = flowFile.getAttribute('filename')
  def path = flowFile.getAttribute('path')
  
            def nextLine = ''
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path+filename), ',');
 
 //Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream,);
 //Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Feuille");
 
            wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            sheet1 = (SXSSFSheet) wb.createSheet('Sheet');
 
            def rowNum = 0;
            while((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                Row currentRow = sheet1.createRow(rowNum++);
                for(int i=0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
                    if(NumberUtils.isDigits(nextLine[i])) {
                        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(nextLine[i]));
                    } else if (NumberUtils.isNumber(nextLine[i])) {
                        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(nextLine[i]));
                    } else {
                        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(nextLine[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
  
 
            //fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(generatedXlsFilePath.trim());
            //wb.write(fileOutputStream);
            generatedXlsFilePath = generatedXlsFilePath + 'SAISIE_MAGASING.XLS'
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(generatedXlsFilePath.trim());
 
            wb.write(outputStream);
            
                wb.close();
                //fileOutputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                reader.close();
                //outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                
  
} as StreamCallback)



flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'filename', filename)
```

The new error:
[image]

Comment: 1. You should not make transfer inside flowfile write 2. I recommend you to use executegroovyscript processor

Comment: I am using executegroovyscript as shwon in the screen. What s wrong with my script §?

Comment: . You should not make transfer inside flowfile write method. You could just drop try-catch because executegroovyscript handles errors correctly

Comment: @daggett I added a new script to my post, I have an other error: No such directory.... how can I pass the content of the flowfile (csv content) to the the Filereader class? Thanks

Comment: flowfile content is coming through `inputStream` and you could change it using `outputStream`. approximately this code should create a new opencsv reader: `new CSVReader( inputStream.newReader('UTF-8') )`

Comment: @daggett Thank you for the help. I share the worked script as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dagget

This is the worked script:

```
@Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.9'))
import com.opencsv.CSVReader
@Grapes(@Grab(group='com.opencsv', module='opencsv', version='4.2'))
//@Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='lang', version='3.12.0'))

@Grapes(@Grab(group='commons-lang', module='commons-lang', version='2.4'))
import org.apache.commons.lang.*


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import java.nio.charset.*
import java.io.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils


def flowFile = session.get()
def date = new Date()

if(!flowFile) return


flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
        SXSSFSheet sheet1 = null;
        CSVReader reader = null;
        Workbook wb = null;
        
  
 
            def nextLine = ''
            reader = new CSVReader( inputStream.newReader('UTF-8') );
            wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
            sheet1 = (SXSSFSheet) wb.createSheet('Sheet');
 
            def rowNum = 0
            while((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                Row currentRow = sheet1.createRow(rowNum++);
                for(int i=0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
                    if(NumberUtils.isDigits(nextLine[i])) {
                        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(nextLine[i]));
                    } else if (NumberUtils.isNumber(nextLine[i])) {
                        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(nextLine[i]));
                    } else {
                        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(nextLine[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
  
 

            wb.write(outputStream);
            reader.close();

} as StreamCallback)


  def filename = 'toto.xlsx'
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'filename', filename) 

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```